# Удаление строки и столбца в матрице, на которых лежит минимальный элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

> Задача: задан двухмерный массив A (матрица) вещественных чисел размерности 3 на 5. Получить из него новый массив V путем удаления из массива A строки и столбца, в которых содержится минимальный элемент.

Написал только *заполнение массива*, *вывод* и *поиск* `минимального элемента`. Не понимаю как *удалить строку или столбец*.

```
import random

dx = 3
dy = 5

A = [[0]*dx for i in range(dy)]

for i in range(dy):
    for j in range(dx):
        A[i][j] = random.randint(-9, 5)

for i in A:
    print(f'{i}', end='')
    print()

min_elem = A[0][0]

for i in range(dy):
    for j in range(dx):
        if A[i][j] < min_elem:
            min_elem = A[i][j]
```

Можете объяснить как это сделать? Желательно с комментариями.

Comment: прошу прощения, прочитал не так, думал надо удалить только строку

Comment: выложил исправленный вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на самом деле тут все просто - достаточно добавить одну строчку

```py
import random

dx = 3
dy = 5

A = [[0]*dx for i in range(dy)]

for i in range(dy):
    for j in range(dx):
        A[i][j] = random.randint(-9, 5)

for i in A:
    print(f'{i}', end='')
    print()

min_elem, min_elem_row, min_elem_column = A[0][0], 0, 0 # ++

for i in range(dy):
    for j in range(dx):
        if A[i][j] < min_elem:
            min_elem = A[i][j]
            min_elem_row = i
            min_elem_column = j

for i in range(dy):
    A[i].pop(min_elem_column)

A.pop(min_elem_row) # ++
```

каждый раз когда мы находим минимум - мы запоминаем его столбец и строку, тогда для столбца мы идем по каждой строке и удаляем такой - то элемент, в конце удаляем все строку, в которой находился `минимум`

Answer (score 1):

Не силен в `Pandas`, уверен там это делается в разы проще, но вот так на коленке вариант:

```
import random


def del_column(mtx: list, index: int) -> list:
    for row in mtx:
        row.pop(index)
    return mtx


if __name__ == '__main__':

    dx = 3
    dy = 5

    A = [[0] * dx for i in range(dy)]

    for i in range(dy):
        for j in range(dx):
            A[i][j] = random.randint(-9, 5)

    for i in A:
        print(f'{i}', end='')
        print()

    min_elem = (A[0][0], 0, 0)

    for i in range(dy):
        for j in range(dx):
            if A[i][j] < min_elem[0]:
                min_elem = (A[i][j], i, j)

    print(A)

    A.pop(min_elem[1])  # Удаляем строку
    del_column(A, min_elem[2])  # Удаляем столбец

    print(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Это решение удалит строку и ряд матрицы с первым минимальным значением, если их несколько.

Исходные:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4)) #size - m X n
```

Матрица:

```
[[0 0 5 1]
 [6 4 3 3]
 [3 9 3 1]]
```

Код:

```
idx = np.where(data == np.min(data))
data = np.delete(data, idx[0][0], axis=0)
data = np.delete(data, idx[1][0], axis=1)
```

Результат:

```
[[4 3 3]
 [9 3 1]]
```